# Error Upgrading Magento

Tags: php, magento, composer-php, magento2

Preface: I'm very new to Magento.

I'm trying to upgrade Magento from 2.0.1 to 2.0.10 via ssh. I'm getting the following Problems:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.10 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.10].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.10 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
```

I added extension=php_mcrypt.so to my php.ini but that didn't seem to fix anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Not really a fix, but I have gotten around this. Upon looking at the php --ini listing, all of the appropriate extensions are installed. It seems the problem might be with the version of php composer is using. Adding --ignore-platform-reqs to my update command I was able to run the update and things appear to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows or Linux?

On Linux it should be 
`extension=mcrypt.so`

On Windows:
`extension=php_mcrypt.dll`

Comment: CentOS 7 w/Plesk. I updated to "extension=mcrypt.so" but still no change to the results.

Comment: Do you reload the fpm/apache process?

Comment: yeah, i restarted PHP-FPM and Apache.